# How to get the Voyager Golden Record music?

Tags: nasa, history, voyager, reference-request

This link
https://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/golden-record/whats-on-the-record/music
From NASA lists the tracks in the Golden Record sent to outer space.

Has anyone come across an easy way to actually listen to all of these songs/music?

There is a playlist on deezer
https://deezer.page.link/zfMLp3JarEM7MqR16

but, obviously, it contains only a small portion of the tracks, and who knows how authentic they are.

An opportunity to purchase audio CD verified by (or originated from) NASA with authentic records would be ideal though.

Comment: I guess you want to have a look at Ozma Records.

Comment: @asdfex Thanks a lot for the clue. Found the site, and price is good, but sold out for now: https://ozmarecords.com/collections/shop/products/voyager-golden-record-book-2xcd